# 90s (or earlier) film or TV show that featured a prison ship whose inmates believed Superman would liberate them

Tags: story-identification, dc, movie, tv, superman

I remember watching a live-action TV episode or film on TV (English, USA) sometime in the early to mid 1990's that featured a prison starship. The prisoners all live in a single "room" on one of the starship decks, separated from the ship's crew and freedom by a long row of prison bars. The prisoners have a shared hope of liberation, some sort of prophecy or promise that someone would come one day to break them out. They don't know who the person is, but they have a copy of that person's coat of arms hidden away on a wall behind a curtain, which turns out to be none other than the Superman "S" shield logo. I do remember that the story gave me quite a foreboding feeling, resembling a horror story more than a traditional superhero flick.

None of the 1970's or 1980's Superman films seem to match. I'm almost certain this was not a DCEU or Arrowverse production as both of those continuities started in the early 2010's, at least 10-15 years after I saw this.

The takes-place-on-a-starship-but-in-a-DC-universe setting reminds me of *DC's Legends of Tomorrow*, but that series was produced 20 years too late to be what I am looking for.

Comment: Live-action Superman in the 90's makes me think of the *Lois and Clark: New adventures of Superman* series, but it sounds a bit cheesy compared to that description.

Comment: @Jenayah I'm seeing that as showing about the same time as when I saw this, but the descriptions don't seem to match. This was more of an Outer Limits or Twilight Zone-esque horror story than a romantic comedy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's from the *Superboy* TV series, namely season 4, episode 13, "West of Alpha Centauri".

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Superboy_episodes):

> Superboy and Lana are kidnapped and taken aboard a spaceship whose destination is a paradise planet just west of Alpha Centauri. **Inside the ship, Superboy finds most of the occupants are prisoners of a deranged captain, and they all believe Superboy is their savior from an old prophecy.** But the jailers are stronger than Superboy, and he can't escape without the help of the prisoners who are too busy fighting among themselves. Superboy must find a way to convince everyone to band together to overthrow the captain and take back control of their ship.